# How to autostart an app after double click it in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, autostart, smplayer

I just noticed this weird behavior on Ubuntu 18.04, I have SMPlayer 18.6.0 installed, if SMP is closed, I double click on a media file, SMP will open up and start playing, but if I minimize it and double click on a media file, I got a notification on my desktop (like the screenshot in the attachment), saying the file is ready, but it did not come into focus, I have to click on the apps icon for it to come into focus. Is there a way for it to come into focus when double click it? I asked SMPlayer Forum, and they said the message does not come from SMP, it's from Ubuntu!

[image: file is ready]